# asp.net single sign on not working

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, forms-authentication, single-sign-on

After a code release, single sign on between two of our sites stopped working. Both sites are run on different subdomains of the same domain. Subdomain x was being used as the sign on server for all other applications. I can't quite wrap my head around why this would be the case. In web.config for both sites the machine and decryption keys are the same. Validation is set to SHA1 and decryption is set to AES. The authentication config reads:

X:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" protection="All" name="Domain.ASPXAUTH" path="/" domain="domain.com" />
</authentication>
```

Y:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="https://x.domain.com/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" protection="All" name="Domain.ASPXAUTH" path="/" domain="domain.com" defaultUrl="http://x.domain.com/" />
</authentication>
```

The SSO was working fine up until this morning. I'm not sure exactly what was changed with the code release and am having issues figuring it out. The two applications are currently running on different app pools (one is x is .net 4.0 while y is .net 2.0) and when I switched them to using the same app pool the SSO worked. However, this is not an option as one of the libraries used in the other site only runs on .NET 2.0. I also tried forcing the machine and decryption keys and validation and decryption algorithms in IIS7 manager at both the top and website levels with no success.

When trying to go to y.domain.com after going to x.domain.com the browser is redirected back to the login page and the following exception is in the event log:

> Forms authentication failed for the
>   request. Reason: The ticket supplied
>   was invalid.

Any ideas?

Comment: You haven't mentioned what the symptons are? What exactly is not working?

Comment: What identity are the app pools running under? Also, what about the library requires it to run on 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by getting patches/hotfixes to Windows and/or .NET. Specifically:

- KB2518870
- KB2656351
- KB2572078
- KB2633870

Answer (score 1):

Do you suspect the config has changed as well?  Because you really need this in the Forms section:

```
enableCrossAppRedirects="true"
```

EDIT: Also make sure that they are using the same encryption keys:

```
<system.web>
   <machineKey validationKey="BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH" decryptionKey="BLAHBLAHBLAH" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"/>
</system.web>
```

It sounds like the redirection is working ok and it's throwing an error when trying to read the ticket.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately, this seemed to have no effected. I added it to both app's web.config.

Comment: Ok, so what are the symptons exactly? Going to need mroe info I'm afraid.

Comment: The original post was edited to show the symptoms. Instead of accepting the domain cookie (like it should) while under separate app pools, the framework logs the aforementioned exception in the event log, and IIS redirects the user back to https://x.domain.com/Account/LogOn when going to http://y.domain.com

Comment: Ok, sounds like it might be having trouble decrypting.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: They *are* using the same encryptionKey, validationKey, validation method, and decryption method. If I set the two applications to use the same application pool then everything works without a hitch. But they can't be on the same app pool because one application requires .NET 2.0 and the other .NET 4.0. I've found a few more forum posts on various sites that seem to have the same issue but I have yet to find a resolution.

Comment: Ok, all of my SSO integrations are using the same version of the framework, so maybe there is an issue somewhere, sorry can't be of much help, good luck finding a solution - post it here when you do if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working adding the following to the 4.0 website, in `web.config` inside configuration tag:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseLegacyFormsAuthenticationTicketCompatibility" value="true" />
    <add key="aspnet:UseLegacyEncryption" value="true" />
    <add key="aspnet:UseLegacyMachineKeyEncryption" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```